# Ember 2, Show a single loading message when the ids where included in the original response

Tags: javascript, performance, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I use very often in my code:

```
{{#each model.posts as |post|}}

  <div>post.title</div>

{{else}}

  <div>Loading the posts...</div>

{{/each}}
```

**But sometimes I don't know if the `model.posts` is empty or not.**

How to show a message instead of loading forever an empty array?

The problem here is that I'm in `/category/2` page, so in `category.hbs` template and posts are **"sideloaded"** in response, like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "categories",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Books"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "posts": {
        "data": [{
          "id": "14",
          "type": "posts"
        }, {
          "id": "15",
          "type": "posts"
        }, {
          "id": "20",
          "type": "posts"
        }]
      }
    }
  },
  "included": [{
    "id": "14",
    "type": "posts",
    "attributes": {
      "commented": true,
      "comments": 10
    }
  }, {
    "id": "15",
    "type": "posts",
    "attributes": {
      "commented": false,
      "comments": 10
    }
  }, {
    "id": "20",
    "type": "posts",
    "attributes": {
      "commented": false,
      "comments": 10
    }
  }]
}
```

I'm using ember-data and my models are:

**category**

```
name: DS.attr('string'),
posts: DS.hasMany('post')
```

**post**

```
commented: DS.attr('string'),
comments: DS.attr('number'),
category: DS.belongsTo('category')
```

Maybe I will create an ember-twiddle, I'm having problem to simulate my problem with ember-data on ember-twiddle...

Comment: I really doubt this is actual your server response. With this response you don't have the state you want to indicate. See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035970/ember-2-strange-behaviour-with-ispending-issettled-isfulfilled-when-using-inc). Can you verify that you actually sent all the posts in the `included` array with your data, and not just the `id`s? Because if you sideload the data you don't have to wait for the data, so there is no request to wait for, and nothing is loaded after you entered the route.

Answer (score 0):

### Using 'links'

From the comments I understand that it's not clear to you how links work. It's fairly simple. Your payload for the category should look like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "categories",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Books"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "posts": {
        "links": {
          "related": "/posts?category_id=2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ember Data will automatically interpret this so that when you get the computed property `model.posts`, it will issue a request to `/posts?category_id=2`.

### Async loading

Since you load the category, and thus the posts, in the `model()` hook of your route, the promise is already loaded by the time the template is rendered. So the `Loading the posts...` template as you have it now will only be shown when a category has no posts, never when it's loading. So as it is now, it's kind of pointless.

If you do want to show a loading animation, you have to load the category not in the `model()` hook of the route but in a computed property on the controller instead. So something like

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  ...
  category: Ember.computed(
    function() {
      return this.store.query('category', {...});
    }
  ),
  ...
});
```

Then you can query the state of the promise in your template. We wrote an Ember addon for that, [ember-promise-block](https://github.com/sutori/ember-promise-block), but I actually recommend you use [ember-deferred-content](https://github.com/danmcclain/ember-deferred-content) instead as it's being kept more up-to-date and is more flexible.

Then you template will look something like:

```
{{#deferred-content category as |d|}}
  {{#d.fulfilled}}
    <div>post.title</div>
  {{/d.fulfilled}}

  {{#d.pending}}
    <div>Loading the posts...</div>
  {{/d.pending}}
{{/deferred-content}}
```

Comment: Thanks dear @yorbro, but this doesn't solve my problem, maybe because of this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035970/ember-2-strange-behaviour-with-ispending-issettled-isfulfilled-when-using-inc). Shortly: I don't want many many HTTP requests. Just one for category (model) and one (non blocking, with loading message) for posts after the first one for model (category)...

Comment: You said your posts are sideloaded together with your category (model), so you only have one request in total no?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem! I need two query, one for the category and one for posts. Because in the model I load category stuff and then I can load posts stuff... This is what I need... No computed properties I think, just query with ember-data and a good sideloading strategy with Rails. I'm trying `coalesceFindRequests` with so many ids querying in just one query, but I'm not so happy of that and then I'm trying "links" relationship, but I don't understand how they work. Documentation is not so good on the web...

Comment: Sorry I read again now. I mean many requests if I remove include in my rails controller and serializer.

Comment: I updated my answer that explains how you can use links in your response. That would be the best solution IMO.

Comment: Thanks, Can you write an example of controller and serializer in Rails for that json response? I'm loosing my mind.

Comment: I'm trying with this guide: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/howto/add_relationship_links.md but my ember also with links like this ({
  "data": {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "categories",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Noir"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "posts": {
        "data": [],
        "links": {
          "related": "/api/posts?category_id=1"
        }
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "/api/categories/1"
    }
  }
}) always call one by one the posts with many many HTTP requests. I'm desperate!